# How to give a column name to sql union form

Tags: sql

I'm trying to give a name to a column with sql UNION syntax, but it doesn't seems to be working.

The simplified version of my code. Note that string 1, 2, 3 are not in any table of my database, I just want it to be displayed as string. However I want to give a name to the column. Please let me know how to do it, thanks.

```
Select 
'String 1'
union

select
'String 2'
Union

SELECT 
'string 3' 

as output
FROM GanttReport(@from,@to,@TypeBigAC)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
SELECT stringName
FROM
(
    Select 'String 1' StringName
    union
    select 'String 2' 
    Union
    SELECT 'string 3'
) t
```

But the alias in the first one (at least).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. However it the error to my parameters Incorrect syntax near '@from'. I did declare the parameter. do you know what's the reason for that?

Comment: @user1918182 What RDBMS you are using? SQL-Server, MySQL, ..? and what is `GanttReport(@from,@to,@TypeBigAC)`?

Answer (score 1):

add an `ALIAS` on it

```
Select 'String 1'  AS columnName
union
select 'String 2'  AS columnName 
Union
SELECT 'string 3'  AS columnName
```